# How do I style a Javascript button using d3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using the d3.js library for JavaScript to create parts of the GUI for my app.
I made a button, and it works as a button, but I want it to be a toggle button. Specifically, I want it to change styles when it is clicked.

For various reasons, I can't touch the css in the stylesheet or the head, I can only use JavaScript.

This is how I am creating the button (there is a div with id = 'menu' in the doc):

```
var menuDiv = d3.select("#menu");
var menuButton = menuDiv.append("button")
    .text("Button")
    .attr("id", "buttonCentre")
    .classed("Button", true)
    .on('click', function(){
        //Do stuff
    });
```

How can I re-style the button? I tried putting things like `d3.select("#buttonCentre").style("background", "#ccc");` into the on_click function, but d3 doesn't recognize the standard css names for styling, it uses different names, and I can't find a list or an equivalence mapping.

Comment: Is it backgroundColor?

Comment: @ksav Just tried it, doesn't change the visual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `background-color` instead of `background`.

```
var menuDiv = d3.select("body");
var menuButton = menuDiv.append("button")
    .text("Button")
    .attr("id", "buttonCentre")
    .classed("button", true)
    .on('click', function(){
        //here this is the button
        d3.select(this).style("background-color", "#ccc")
    });
```

Here is a working [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkqA9kcnnbMSIJWXvpF3?p=preview)

Comment: probably a good idea to do `d3.select(this).style("background-color", "#ccc")` rather than target by id.

Comment: @Cyril This worked. Where did you get this from? Is there a list of d3 styles somewhere?

Comment: Nopes there is no particular style for D3. These are normal styles you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp